# How get backgroundColor from ImageView

Tags: java, android

How get backgroundColor from ImageView? My code example
        `ImageView imageViewNote = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.chooseColorEdit);`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get background like below code

```
Drawable bgDrawable = imageViewNote.getBackground();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (it works only in case your background is actually a color, otherwise, you don't really have a "background" color"):

```
    Drawable background = userNameTextView.getBackground();
    if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
        int color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor();
        // Use color here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try get ColorDrawable of the ImageView?